# I Want to display image in picturebox directly after loading through imread (opencv)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, opencv, picturebox

I am making a windows form application in Visual Studio 2010.
I have taken a `button` and a `picture box`. 
I am reading an image from memory and I want this image to be displayed in the picture box directly without saving it in the memory.

Following code is saving the image and then loading it into the picture box.
How can i improve this code to do the desired task.

```
 #pragma endregion  private: System::Void btn1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
> 
>                Mat im = imread("C:/Users/Ravi Sharma/Desktop/Koala.jpg");
>     if (im.empty()) 
>     {
>         cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
>         exit;
>     }
> 
>   imwrite("C:/Users/Ravi Sharma/Desktop/Koalanew.jpg",im);
>     imshow("Image", im);  
>  picturebox->Image=Image::FromFile("C:/Users/Ravi Sharma/Desktop/Koalanew.jpg");
>            }
```

After making some improvements 
My new code is

```
> System::Void btn1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
> {
>     cv::Mat cvImage = cv::imread("C:/Users/Ravi Sharma/Desktop/Koala.jpg");
> 
>     if (cvImage.empty()) 
>     {
>         cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
>         exit;
>     }
> 
>     Bitmap^ bmImage = gcnew Bitmap(cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows, 3 * cvImage.cols, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, IntPtr(cvImage.data));
>     Image^ image = static_cast<Bitmap^>(bmImage); 
>      picturebox->Image=Image.bmImage;
>       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Bitmap` from a pointer to an array of bytes that contains the pixel data (in your case this is a `cv::Mat` object), and then just cast it to an `Image`:

```
System::Void btn1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    cv::Mat cvImage = cv::imread("C:/Users/Ravi Sharma/Desktop/Koala.jpg");

    if (cvImage.empty()) 
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot load image!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    DrawCvImage(cvImage);
}

System::Void DrawCvImage(const cv::Mat& cvImage) 
{
    // only color images are supported
    assert(cvImage.type() == CV_8UC3);

    if ((pictureBox->Image == nullptr) || (pictureBox->Width != cvImage.cols) || (pictureBox->Height != cvImage.rows))
    { 
        pictureBox->Width = cvImage.cols; 
        pictureBox->Height = cvImage.rows; 
        pictureBox->Image = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows); 
    }

    // Create System::Drawing::Bitmap from cv::Mat
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmpImage = gcnew Bitmap(
        cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows, cvImage.step, 
        System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, 
        System::IntPtr(cvImage.data)
    ); 

    // Draw Bitmap over a PictureBox
    Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pictureBox->Image); 

    g->DrawImage(bmpImage, 0, 0, cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows);  
    pictureBox->Refresh(); 

    delete g; 
}
```

Comment: How I would display the bitmap image in picture box? @Kornel

Comment: just copy bitmap to `pictureBox.Image`

Comment: Now I have edited my code but it is still not loading the image.
Is it the way to copy Bitmap Image to Picture Box @Kornel ?

Comment: Thanx for your help. I used your code but it is not showing the image in picturebox. Please help me to display the image in picture box.